# Why the youtube video doesnt displayed properly on my improvised html file?

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

I learned how to send an https packet and get an answer to it.

I did this action to the next youtube Web page:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_ub7Etch2U

Well - I got the correct html file, and saved it to some html file I created.

The upper part of the code, belongs to the video representation.
Here is the upper part:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://support.google.com/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."
Expires: Tue, 27 Apr 1971 19:44:06 EST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Thu, 28 Sep 2017 11:33:55 GMT
Server: YouTube Frontend Proxy
Set-Cookie: VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=iyLPdRsJ1ew; path=/; domain=.youtube.com; expires=Tue, 29-May-2018 23:26:55 GMT; httponly
Set-Cookie: PREF=f1=50000000; path=/; domain=.youtube.com; expires=Tue, 29-May-2018 23:26:55 GMT
Set-Cookie: YSC=9NDjr8BhrrU; path=/; domain=.youtube.com; httponly
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35"
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

15cb
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" data-cast-api-enabled="true"><head><style name="www-roboto" >@font
-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:italic;font-weight:400;src:local('Roboto Italic'),local('Roboto-Italic'),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/W4wDsBUluyw0tK3tykhXEfesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:italic;font-weight:500;src:local('Roboto Medium Italic'),local('Roboto-MediumItalic'),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto
/v16/OLffGBTaF0XFOW1gnuHF0Z0EAVxt0G0biEntp43Qt6E.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local('Roboto Regular'),local('Roboto-Regular'),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/zN7GBFwfMP4uA6AR0HCoLQ.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;src:local('Roboto Medium'),local('Roboto-Medium'),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/RxZJdnzeo3R5zSexge8UUaCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf)format('truetype');}</style><script name="www-roboto" >if (document.fonts && document.fonts.load) {document.fonts.load("400 10pt Roboto", "E");document.fonts.load("500 10pt Roboto", "E");}</script><script >var ytcsi = {gt: function(n) {n = (n || '') + 'data_';return ytcsi[n] || (ytcsi[n] = {tick: {},info: {}});},now: window.performance && window.performance.timing &&window.performance.now ? function() {return window.performance.timing.navigationStart + window.performance.now();} : function() {return (new Date()).getTime();},tick: function(l, 
t, n) {ticks = ytcsi.gt(n).tick;var v = t || ytcsi.now();if (ticks[l]) {ticks['_' + l] = (ticks['_' + l] || [ticks[l]]);ticks['_' + l].push(v);}ticks[l] = v;},info: function(k, v, n) {ytcsi.gt(n).info[k] = v;},setStart: function(s, t, n) {ytcsi.info('yt_sts', s, n);ytcsi.tick('_start', t, n);}};(function(w, d) {ytcsi.setStart('dhs', w.performance ? w.performance.timing.respo
nseStart : null);var isPrerender = (d.visibilityState || d.webkitVisibilityState) == 'prerender';var vName = d.webkitVisibilityState ? 'webkitvisibilitychange' : 'visibilitychange';if (isPrerender) {ytcsi.info('prerender', 1);var startTick = function() {ytcsi.setStart('dhs');d.removeEventListener(vName, startTick);};d.addEventListener(vName, startTick, false);}if (d.addEventListener) {d.addEventListener(vName, function() {ytcsi.tick('vc');}, false);}var slt = function(el, t) {setTimeout(function() {var n = ytcsi.now();el.loadTime = n;if (el.slt) {el.slt();}}, t);};w.__ytRIL = function(el) {if (!el.getAttribute('data-thumb')) {if (w.requestAnimationFrame) {w.requestAnimationFrame(function() {slt(el, 0);});} else {slt(el, 16);}}};})(window, document);</script><script >var ytcfg = {d: function() {return (window.yt && yt.config_) || ytcfg.data_ || (ytcfg.data_ = {});},get: function(k, o) {return (k in ytcfg.d()) ? ytcfg.d()[k] : o;},set: function() {var a = arguments;if (a.length > 1) {ytcfg.d()[a[0]] = a[1];} el
se {for (var k in a[0]) {ytcfg.d()[k] = a[0][k];}}}};</script>  <script>ytcfg.set("EXP_HTML5_SERVERSIDE_PAGEAD_ID_SETS_COOKIE", false);ytcfg.set("LACT", null);</script>





  <script>
        (function(){var b={a:"content-snap-width-1",b:"content-snap-width-2",c:"content-snap-width-3"};function f(){var a=[],c;for(c in b)a.push(b[c]);return a}
function h(a){var c=f().conca
t(["guide-pinned","show-guide"]),e=c.length,g=[];a.replace(/\S+/g,function(a){for(var d=0;d<e;d++)if(a==c[d])return;g.push(a)});
return g}
;function k(a,c,e){var g=document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0],d=h(g.className);a&&1251<=(window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth)&&(d.push("guide-pinned"),c&&d.push("show-guide"));e&&(e=(window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth)-21-50,1251<=(window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth)&&a&&c&&(e-=230),d.push(1262<=e?"content-snap-width-3":1056<=e?"content-snap-width-2":"content-snap-width-1"));g.className=d.join(" ")}
var l=["yt","www","masthead","sizing","runBeforeBodyIsReady"],m=this;l[0]in m||!m.execScript||m.execScript("var "+l[0]);for(var n;l.length&&(n=l.shift());)l.length||void 0===k?m[n]&&m[n]!==Object.prototype[n]?m=m[n]:m=m[n]={}:m[n]=k;}).call(this);

      try {window.ytbuffer = {};ytbuffer.handleClick = function(e) {var element = e.target || e.srcElement;while (element.parentElement) {if (/(^| )yt-can-buffer( |$)/
.test(element.className)) {window.ytbuffer = {bufferedClick: e};element.className += ' yt-is-buffered';break;}element = element.parentElement;}};if (document.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener('click', ytbuffer.handleClick);} else {document.attachEvent('onclick', ytbuffer.handleClick);}} catch(e) {}

    yt.www.masthead.sizing.runBeforeBodyIsReady(false,false,true)
;
  </script>

      <script src="/yts/jsbin/scheduler-vflEJvYEi/scheduler.js" type="text/javascript" name="scheduler/scheduler" ></script>


    <script >var ytimg = {};ytimg.count = 1;ytimg.preload = function(src) {var img = new Image();var count = ++ytimg.count;ytimg[count] = img;img.onload = img.onerror = function() {delete ytimg[count];};img.src = src;};</script>


      <script src="/yts/jsbin/www-pagead-id-vflJbL1IV/www-pagead-id.js" type="text/javascript" name="www-pagead-id/www-pagead-id"  async></script>

      <script src="/yts/jsbin/player-vfls3Lf3-/en_US/base.js"  name="player/base" ></script>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/yts/cssbin/www-core-vflZ2IKLG.css" name="www-core">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/yts/cssbin/player-vflejtddo/www-player.css" name="player/www-player">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/yts/cssbin/www-pageframe-vflZFBWKu.css" name="www-pageframe">



      <script>ytimg.preload("https:\/\/r4---sn-oxu8pnpvo-ua8s.googlevideo.com\/generate_204?conn2");ytimg.preload("https:\/\/r4---sn-oxu8pnpvo-ua8s.googlevideo.com\/generate_204");</script>
```

But after mooving the header part, and adding `www.youtube.co.il` before any link, the upper part looks more like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" data-cast-api-enabled="true"><head><style name="www-roboto" >@font
-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:italic;font-weight:400;src:local('Roboto Italic'),local('Roboto-Italic'),url(https://www.youtube.com/fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/W4wDsBUluyw0tK3tykhXEfesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:italic;font-weight:500;src:local('Roboto Medium Italic'),local('Roboto-MediumItalic'),url(https://www.youtube.com/fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto
/v16/OLffGBTaF0XFOW1gnuHF0Z0EAVxt0G0biEntp43Qt6E.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local('Roboto Regular'),local('Roboto-Regular'),url(https://www.youtube.com/fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/zN7GBFwfMP4uA6AR0HCoLQ.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;src:local('Roboto Medium'),local('Roboto-Medium'),url(https://www.youtube.com/fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/RxZJdnzeo3R5zSexge8UUaCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf)format('truetype');}</style><script name="www-roboto" >if (document.fonts && document.fonts.load) {document.fonts.load("400 10pt Roboto", "E");document.fonts.load("500 10pt Roboto", "E");}</script><script >var ytcsi = {gt: function(n) {n = (n || '') + 'data_';return ytcsi[n] || (ytcsi[n] = {tick: {},info: {}});},now: window.performance && window.performance.timing &&window.performance.now ? function() {return window.performance.timing.navigationStart + window.performance.now();} : function() {return (new Date()).getTime();},tick: function(l, 
t, n) {ticks = ytcsi.gt(n).tick;var v = t || ytcsi.now();if (ticks[l]) {ticks['_' + l] = (ticks['_' + l] || [ticks[l]]);ticks['_' + l].push(v);}ticks[l] = v;},info: function(k, v, n) {ytcsi.gt(n).info[k] = v;},setStart: function(s, t, n) {ytcsi.info('yt_sts', s, n);ytcsi.tick('_start', t, n);}};(function(w, d) {ytcsi.setStart('dhs', w.performance ? w.performance.timing.respo
nseStart : null);var isPrerender = (d.visibilityState || d.webkitVisibilityState) == 'prerender';var vName = d.webkitVisibilityState ? 'webkitvisibilitychange' : 'visibilitychange';if (isPrerender) {ytcsi.info('prerender', 1);var startTick = function() {ytcsi.setStart('dhs');d.removeEventListener(vName, startTick);};d.addEventListener(vName, startTick, false);}if (d.addEventListener) {d.addEventListener(vName, function() {ytcsi.tick('vc');}, false);}var slt = function(el, t) {setTimeout(function() {var n = ytcsi.now();el.loadTime = n;if (el.slt) {el.slt();}}, t);};w.__ytRIL = function(el) {if (!el.getAttribute('data-thumb')) {if (w.requestAnimationFrame) {w.requestAnimationFrame(function() {slt(el, 0);});} else {slt(el, 16);}}};})(window, document);</script><script >var ytcfg = {d: function() {return (window.yt && yt.config_) || ytcfg.data_ || (ytcfg.data_ = {});},get: function(k, o) {return (k in ytcfg.d()) ? ytcfg.d()[k] : o;},set: function() {var a = arguments;if (a.length > 1) {ytcfg.d()[a[0]] = a[1];} el
se {for (var k in a[0]) {ytcfg.d()[k] = a[0][k];}}}};</script>  <script>ytcfg.set("EXP_HTML5_SERVERSIDE_PAGEAD_ID_SETS_COOKIE", false);ytcfg.set("LACT", null);</script>





  <script>
        (function(){var b={a:"content-snap-width-1",b:"content-snap-width-2",c:"content-snap-width-3"};function f(){var a=[],c;for(c in b)a.push(b[c]);return a}
function h(a){var c=f().conca
t(["guide-pinned","show-guide"]),e=c.length,g=[];a.replace(/\S+/g,function(a){for(var d=0;d<e;d++)if(a==c[d])return;g.push(a)});
return g}
;function k(a,c,e){var g=document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0],d=h(g.className);a&&1251<=(window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth)&&(d.push("guide-pinned"),c&&d.push("show-guide"));e&&(e=(window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth)-21-50,1251<=(window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth)&&a&&c&&(e-=230),d.push(1262<=e?"content-snap-width-3":1056<=e?"content-snap-width-2":"content-snap-width-1"));g.className=d.join(" ")}
var l=["yt","www","masthead","sizing","runBeforeBodyIsReady"],m=this;l[0]in m||!m.execScript||m.execScript("var "+l[0]);for(var n;l.length&&(n=l.shift());)l.length||void 0===k?m[n]&&m[n]!==Object.prototype[n]?m=m[n]:m=m[n]={}:m[n]=k;}).call(this);

      try {window.ytbuffer = {};ytbuffer.handleClick = function(e) {var element = e.target || e.srcElement;while (element.parentElement) {if (/(^| )yt-can-buffer( |$)/
.test(element.className)) {window.ytbuffer = {bufferedClick: e};element.className += ' yt-is-buffered';break;}element = element.parentElement;}};if (document.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener('click', ytbuffer.handleClick);} else {document.attachEvent('onclick', ytbuffer.handleClick);}} catch(e) {}

    yt.www.masthead.sizing.runBeforeBodyIsReady(false,false,true)
;
  </script>

      <script src="https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/scheduler-vflEJvYEi/scheduler.js" type="text/javascript" name="scheduler/scheduler" ></script>


    <script >var ytimg = {};ytimg.count = 1;ytimg.preload = function(src) {var img = new Image();var count = ++ytimg.count;ytimg[count] = img;img.onload = img.onerror = function() {delete ytimg[count];};img.src = src;};</script>


      <script src="https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-pagead-id-vflJbL1IV/www-pagead-id.js" type="text/javascript" name="www-pagead-id/www-pagead-id"  async></script>

      <script src="https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-vfls3Lf3-/en_US/base.js"  name="player/base" ></script>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.youtube.com/yts/cssbin/www-core-vflZ2IKLG.css" name="www-core">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.youtube.com/yts/cssbin/player-vflejtddo/www-player.css" name="player/www-player">

<script>
ytimg.preload("https:\/\/r4---sn-oxu8pnpvo-ua8s.googlevideo.com\/generate_204?conn2");
ytimg.preload("https:\/\/r4---sn-oxu8pnpvo-ua8s.googlevideo.com\/generate_204");
</script>
```

After Im doing this, so finally I get to see the black big video window on the screen, and some other youtube designs (like the description, etcedera...).
But - I still cannot show the video on the screen.
What I see is this thing:
[The webpage after saving it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3i0u.png)

What exactly do I miss that I cannot display properly the video?
Should I add the `www.youtube.com` link before any link I see to get it work?

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: @Xufox Thanks. It shows me zero erros and warnings, and still doesnt work.